# When should I call PyGILState_Ensure?

Tags: python, python-c-api

I am writting performance aware code in C and wrap the functions parameter with Python C API and ctypes.

I am confused about `PyGILState_Ensure`. What does it protect? When should I lock or release the GIL.

For example:

```
extern "C" DLL PyObject * foo(PyObject * capsule, PyObject *pystr) {
    MyClass *pointer = PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule, "MyClass");
    string s = convert_python_string_to_std_string(pystr);
    auto state = PyGILState_Ensure();
    try {
        vector<string> strs = a_very_computation_function(pointer, s);
        PyGILState_Release(state);
        PyObject *output = convert_std_string_to_python_string_list(strs);
        return output
    }
    catch (std::exception e) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, e.what());
        PyGILState_Release(state);
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

In python, ctypes wraps it in such way:

```
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("mydll.dll")
    lib.foo.argtypes = [ py_object, py_object ] #capsule, str
    lib.foo.restype = py_object # [str]
```

foo function take a python string like `"abcd"`, do some heavy calculation.
then return a list of string in python like `["123","qwer","xyz"]`.

`foo` function does NOT create any thread.

Since `a_very_computation_function` can take very long time. I should release the GIL during its exection?

Does reading stuff from `PyObject` need to be protected from GIL(within "ensure" and "release")?

Does generateing new `PyObject` need to be protected from GIL?

Does calling `PyErr_SetString` need to be protected from GIL?

Where should I add `PyGILState_Ensure` and `PyGILState_Release` exactly?

Comment: It’s a bit weird to use `ctypes` with a C(++) function that is already doing almost all the work of being accessible from Python directly.

Comment: You say `foo` doesn’t create threads.  Is there *anything* multithreaded here?  If not, you needn’t do anything.